# Is it possible to avoid subqueries for this kind of query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, grouping, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have a table with this kind of data:

```
Parent  Value           DateFor       ValueType
3177    50.110000       2016-03-05    1
3177    254390.000000   2016-03-05    2
3177    50.110000       2016-03-06    1
3177    254390.000000   2016-03-06    2
3294    40.800000       2016-03-05    1
3294    20280.000000    2016-03-05    2
```

My table has a PRIMARY index on Id (id not shown here) and a FOREIGN relationship to a parent table, with the help of the `Parent` column.

I would like to select the latest value by value type, for each Parent:

```
3177    50.110000       2016-03-06    1
3177    254390.000000   2016-03-06    2
3294    40.800000       2016-03-05    1
3294    20280.000000    2016-03-05    2
```

Explication: I ignore both values for 2015-03-05 for parent 3177, since it has data for 2016-03-06. But I take the data from 2016-03-05 for parent 3294 since it's the latest I have.

What is the most performant query that would achieve this? Because my table has millions of rows...

Is it possible to avoid sub-queries?

Comment: `How to optimize performance for this query?` Where is the query?

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: @lad2025 I have basic `SELECT` with a where filter where I provide one parent and no grouping, but I don't know how to build a query without filter and with grouping, taking the top 1 by date, for all the data...

Comment: @trincot: SQL Server, sorry

Comment: It is too broad. First your data sample it to small and it is a bit not clear. Second you don't show us your table/index structure. Third: Why do you store duplicates?

Comment: What is not clear? I store duplicates because it is the way it is...I need to favor performance over storage size optimization.

Comment: Do you even have `CLUSTERED INDEX` or is your table a heap? Please post table creation script.

Comment: It is a simple table with a CLUSTER INDEX on the Id field. Also it has a relationship to a parent via the `Parent` column pointing to the parent `Id`.

Comment: The question is about performance yes, but more about an efficient SELECT query that will maybe require TOP 1 or subqueries or a GROUP BY clause...this is my question, I am not sure how to build such an efficient query.

Comment: @ibiza Why are you trying to avoid sub queries even if they make the query more efficient?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Good question...I assumed subqueries were inefficient, that would not be the case?

Comment: It is possible to avoid subqueries, but the query would be much, much more expensive to run.  Subqueries are not necessarily inefficient.

Comment: @ibiza Normally, [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) are what you'll want to watch out for. Of course it's as easy to write an inefficient subquery as it is to write an inefficient query though, so exceptions apply as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using analytic functions along with a covering index should get you good performance sacrificing some disk space;

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test 
       ON myTable([Parent], [ValueType], [DateFor] DESC) INCLUDE ([Value]);

GO

SELECT [Parent], [Value], [DateFor], [ValueType]
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY [Parent], [ValueType] ORDER BY [DateFor] DESC) rn
  FROM myTable
) z
WHERE rn=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! Question : Why `INCLUDE ([Value])` rather than putting `[Value]` in the index itself (with the other columns in the `ON` clause)?

Comment: @ibiza Here you can use either, `INCLUDE` tends to save some space though. For more detail, you can for example take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806(v=sql.120).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The question is overly broad, thus the answer is sort of generic. Use SQL Query w/sub-query, or Temp Table (the latter may result in better performance). First, get the earliest date (minimum value) by `SELECT MAX(DateFor) as MinDate FROM [YourTable] Group BY [Parent], [ValueType]`, then run second `SELECT` statement using `MinDate` in `WHERE` clause. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that might also have good performance is:

```
SELECT [Parent], [Value], [DateFor], [ValueType]
FROM t
WHERE DateFor = (SELECT MAX(t2.DateFor)
                 FROM t t2
                 WHERE t2.Parent = t.Parent AND t2.ValueType = t.ValueType
                );
```

This wants the same index that Joachim suggests.  Under some circumstances, this might be marginally faster.  You can test the two on your data.